# Making multiple images animate sequentially

Tags: android, animation

Total noob here, so forgive my ignorance. I've found some code to animate an ImageView:

```
public void startAnimatedBackground(Integer num) {

    ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = null;
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            imageSwitcher = img_0;
            break;
        case 1:
            imageSwitcher = img_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            imageSwitcher = img_2;
            break;
        case 3:
            imageSwitcher = img_3;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(aniIn);
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(aniOut);
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(images[index]);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final ImageSwitcher finalImageSwitcher = imageSwitcher;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isRunning) {
                index++;
                index = index % images.length;
                finalImageSwitcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
                handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);

}

public View makeView() {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    isRunning = false;
    super.finish();
}}
```

I'm creating some of the needed code on the onCreate():

```
    private int index = 0;
private boolean isRunning = true;
Animation aniIn;
Animation aniOut;
ImageSwitcher img_0,img_1,img_2,img_3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_walk_in_progress);
    aniIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);
    aniOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);

    aniIn.setDuration(500);
    aniOut.setDuration(500);
    img_0 = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher_accept);
    img_1 = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher_on_way);
    img_2 = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher_in_progress);
    img_3 = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher_finished);
    startAnimatedBackground(0);
}
```

Now the first one works fine. Now in a Activity I'm trying to switch this to have the 2nd image start animating:

Edit: This new "activity" isn't one that is inflating a view. The new activity is a GCM Intent Service that is simply listening for notifications and updating my notification information. When I get this notification, I want to take the view that is currently showing on the users screen already and update the animation to switch it to the 2nd image.

```
            WalkInProgress walk = new WalkInProgress();
        walk.startAnimatedBackground(1);
```

This causes an error:

> 02-01 16:03:04.766  23805-24580/ly.leash.Leashly I/System.out﹕ null
>   02-01 16:03:04.778  23805-24580/ly.leash.Leashly E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GcmIntentService]
>       Process: ly.leash.Leashly, PID: 23805
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageSwitcher.setInAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference
>               at ly.leash.Leashly.WalkInProgress.startAnimatedBackground(WalkInProgress.java:179)
>               at ly.leash.Leashly.GcmIntentService.sendNotification(GcmIntentService.java:96)
>               at ly.leash.Leashly.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:72)
>               at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

So for whatever reason the animation is going back to null.

I've tried declaring it all in the startAnimatedBackground function instead of onCreate, but that causes errors as well:

> 02-01 16:15:10.488  25553-25930/ly.leash.Leashly E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GcmIntentService]
>       Process: ly.leash.Leashly, PID: 25553
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:85)
>               at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:74)
>               at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:73)
>               at ly.leash.Leashly.WalkInProgress.startAnimatedBackground(WalkInProgress.java:152)
>               at ly.leash.Leashly.GcmIntentService.sendNotification(GcmIntentService.java:96)
>               at ly.leash.Leashly.GcmIntentService.onHandleIntent(GcmIntentService.java:72)
>               at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

The error is at this line:

```
        aniIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Now in a different part of the app`? A different activity?

Comment: Yes, a different activity. Sorry

Comment: My guess would be that `img_1` is not in this new activity's layout file. Am I right?

Comment: No it is in the original activity's layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the null pointer is that the `ImageSwitcher` you are trying to access is in a different activity. You would have to instantiate it again in this new activity using `img_1 = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher_on_way);` (assuming the `ImageSwitcher` widget with id `switcher_on_way` is in the new activity's XML layout file).

**Update**

In order to send a message from the GCM Intent Service to your currently running activity, you would need to send a broadcast to the activity.

After confirming that the user is currently viewing your activity, create an `Intent` and send a broadcast to the activity:

```
/* create intent */
Intent intent = new Intent("my_animation");
intent.putExtra("message", message); <-- replace this with what you
                                         want to broadcast to your
                                         activity (which would be an
                                         integer specifying the new 
                                         ImageSwitcher)

/* send broadcast */
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your activity, create a `BroadcastReceiver` that would process the broadcast intent.

```
/* this handler will process the broadcast intent */
private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Extract data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        // you could start your animation here 
    }
};
```

Register the `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume` and unregister it in `onPause`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter("my_animation"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(messageReceiver);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry just got back from a trip! Thank you for the answer, you're saying the switcher_on_way must be in the new activity? Check my edit above. The activity that is calling the code  to animate the 2nd image isn't really one that is currently in view, it is just a GCM service that sees that we have an updated GCM message and is trying to update the image for the already showing activity above

Comment: Hey, thanks. I've done exactly as you have done above and I am not getting to the onReceive function in my original activity. I also tried adding in the details of the class I want to send to in the Intent(), but that still didn't change anything. What am I missing? I didn't know about broadcast receivers, these are great! I'm going to read up and may be able to answer my own question

Comment: @user1610719 I'm not sure why it's not working, but I noticed I omitted the intent action (when creating the `Intent` and with the `IntentFilter`). I have added it. If it doesn't solve your problem, I hope you find a solution soon.